# Nexus 5 Lollipop losing cell signal when wifi connected

Tags: bugs, 5.1-lollipop, cellular-radio

I believe I first noticed this when I got version 5.1, and am still getting the issue with 5.1.1. If I keep the phone with wifi off, the phone works fine. If I connect to a wifi access point, at first it will first switch from LTE to the AT&T 3g connection, then, soon after, all cell phone connectivity drops, I can neither make/receive call nor send/receive text messages unless I disconnect wifi and wait for it a bit, until it reconnects to LTE.
Anybody else experiencing this?
Thanks.

Comment: is wifi calling enabled ?

Comment: No it isn't. No sort of wifi calling at all running.

Comment: Well, lately it's been working better, perhaps due to a patch, now maybe they can work on the Bluetooth?